# Three-level multilevel model specification problem with R2WinBUGS

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm trying to apply the method used by Gelman & Hill (2007: p348) on the radon data set, with my own data. It's a multilevel model problem whereby I need to specify three levels - repeated broadband speed measurements (level 1) nested within local authorities (level 2) (J), finally nested within regions (level 3) (K). The dependent variable is broadband speed (y) and the independent variable is population density (x).

Although the model is apparently syntactically correct, WinBUGS keeps saying I have an undefined variable, but I'm not sure where my code is mis- specified. I'm not confident the nesting is correct, and also the specification of both the inits and parameters in the R code.  I know a lot of people have moved onto using rstan, but I still feel I need to learn basic WinBUGS before I move towards it.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Here's a reproducible example:

```
###WinBUGS model
model {

#level 1
for (i in 1:n){
y[i] ~ dnorm (y.hat[i], tau.y)
y.hat[i] <- a[laid[i]] + b*x[i]}

b ~ dnorm (0, .0001)
tau.y <- pow(sigma.y, -2)
sigma.y ~ dunif (0, 100)

#level 2
for (j in 1:J){
a[j] ~ dnorm (mu.a, tau.a)}

mu.a ~ dnorm (0, .0001)
tau.a <- pow(sigma.a, -2)
sigma.a ~ dunif (0, 100)

#level 3
for (k in 1:K){
a[k] ~ dnorm (mu.b, tau.b)}

mu.b ~ dnorm (0, .0001)
tau.b <- pow(sigma.b, -2)
sigma.b ~ dunif (0, 100)
}
```

And here's my R code and data:

```
require(R2WinBUGS)
 n<- 344 
 J <- 86
 K <- 13
 laid <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,
          6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,
          11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,
          16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,
          21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,
          26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,
          31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,
          36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,
          41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,
          46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,
          51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,53,53,53,53,54,54,54,54,55,55,55,55,
          56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,58,58,58,58,59,59,59,59,60,60,60,60,
          61,61,61,61,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,64,64,64,64,65,65,65,65,
          66,66,66,66,67,67,67,67,68,68,68,68,69,69,69,69,70,70,70,70,
          71,71,71,71,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,75,75,75,75,
          76,76,76,76,77,77,77,77,78,78,78,78,79,79,79,79,80,80,80,80,
          81,81,81,81,82,82,82,82,83,83,83,83,84,84,84,84,85,85,85,85,
          86,86,86,86)
 rnid <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
          2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,
          3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
          4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
          5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
          6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
          7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,
          8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,
          9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
          10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
          11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
          11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,
          12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,
          13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,
          13,13,13,13)
      x <- c(7.59,7.6,7.6,7.6,7.53,7.53,7.54,7.54,8.38,8.39,
        8.4,8.41,7.37,7.37,7.38,7.38,7.2,7.2,7.2,7.21,
        7.79,7.8,7.81,7.82,7.72,7.72,7.72,7.73,7.66,7.67,
        7.67,7.67,7.67,7.68,7.68,7.69,7.43,7.43,7.44,7.44,
        7.43,7.43,7.43,7.43,8.33,8.34,8.35,8.35,7.16,7.16,
        7.16,7.17,7.49,7.49,7.49,7.49,7.62,7.62,7.62,7.62,
        6.56,6.57,6.57,6.58,6.28,6.28,6.28,6.28,6.8,6.8,
        6.81,6.81,7.31,7.32,7.33,7.33,7.25,7.25,7.25,7.25,
        7.81,7.82,7.83,7.85,7.8,7.8,7.81,7.81,7.74,7.74,
        7.74,7.74,7.6,7.6,7.61,7.61,8.3,8.31,8.31,8.32,
        8.08,8.09,8.12,8.14,8.07,8.07,8.07,8.08,8.19,8.2,
        8.21,8.22,7.06,7.06,7.07,7.07,7.86,7.87,7.87,7.88,
        8.19,8.19,8.2,8.2,7.26,7.27,7.27,7.27,6.33,6.34,
        6.34,6.35,6.94,6.95,6.95,6.96,7.22,7.23,7.23,7.24,
        6.87,6.87,6.88,6.89,6.89,6.89,6.9,6.9,7.85,7.85,
        7.85,7.86,6.31,6.31,6.31,6.31,6.84,6.84,6.85,6.85,
        6.28,6.28,6.28,6.28,5.44,5.44,5.44,5.45,4.14,4.14,
        4.14,4.14,5.76,5.77,5.77,5.77,7.37,7.37,7.37,7.38,
        7.02,7.03,7.04,7.04,5.88,5.89,5.89,5.89,6.98,6.98,
        6.98,6.98,8.31,8.31,8.31,8.3,8.19,8.19,8.19,8.19,
        4.94,4.94,4.94,4.94,6.72,6.72,6.72,6.72,5.29,5.29,
        5.3,5.3,6.59,6.6,6.61,6.62,8.07,8.07,8.08,8.08,
        8.41,8.42,8.42,8.44,4.56,4.54,4.56,4.57,8.31,8.33,
        8.33,8.35,4.43,4.44,4.45,4.45,6.35,6.36,6.36,6.37,
        4.56,4.57,4.57,4.57,7.89,7.89,7.89,7.9,6.21,6.23,
        6.24,6.25,8.27,8.28,8.29,8.3,6.3,6.3,6.31,6.32,
        6.27,6.28,6.29,6.3,5.01,5.02,5.03,5.03,4.9,4.94,
        4.94,4.94,8.08,8.08,8.09,8.09,7.64,7.65,7.65,7.66,
        8.29,8.3,8.31,8.33,7.73,7.74,7.74,7.75,6.81,6.83,
        6.84,6.84,4.98,4.99,4.99,5,6.29,6.3,6.31,6.32,
        8.45,8.46,8.47,8.49,5.8,5.81,5.83,5.84,5.88,5.9,
        5.91,5.93,8.34,8.34,8.34,8.36,6.88,6.88,6.89,6.91,
        7.22,7.23,7.24,7.26,8.56,8.57,8.58,8.6,6.95,6.96,
        6.97,6.98,5.39,5.39,5.4,5.4,8.25,8.27,8.28,8.29,
        8.37,8.38,8.39,8.4)
 y <- c(2.1,2.77,2.95,3.3,1.96,2.57,2.82,3.12,2.1,2.56,
           2.88,3.18,1.95,2.72,2.96,3.31,1.93,2.39,2.83,3.2,
           2.21,2.83,3.03,3.35,2.17,2.82,3.1,3.44,2.04,2.54,
           2.83,3.15,2.14,2.68,3.07,3.36,2.15,2.63,3.03,3.36,
           2.05,2.49,2.91,3.28,2.25,2.67,2.96,3.33,2.08,2.56,
           2.99,3.31,2.17,2.61,2.83,3.29,2.12,2.54,2.8,3.15,
           1.93,2.53,2.71,3.03,1.97,2.53,2.72,3.07,1.97,2.42,
           2.63,2.98,1.97,2.53,2.73,3.04,2.17,2.57,2.97,3.23,
           2.17,2.69,2.93,3.23,2.09,2.71,2.92,3.25,2.1,2.58,
           3.03,3.4,1.93,2.39,2.89,3.22,2.19,2.71,3.03,3.36,
           2.12,2.5,2.9,3.23,2.14,2.6,3.03,3.36,2.16,2.61,
           2.91,3.2,2.12,2.83,3.09,3.41,2.1,2.6,2.96,3.27,
           2.21,2.95,3.1,3.47,2.12,2.59,2.95,3.25,1.92,2.5,
           2.64,2.97,1.95,2.45,2.79,3.12,2.07,2.54,2.91,3.23,
           1.92,2.42,2.66,2.99,2.07,2.93,3.14,3.48,2.2,2.92,
           3.15,3.44,2.15,2.87,3.1,3.42,2.12,2.74,3.14,3.46,
           2.05,2.57,3.03,3.38,1.84,2.24,2.47,2.75,1.84,2.12,
           2.35,2.67,1.9,2.5,2.76,3.05,2,2.42,2.87,3.24,
           2.01,2.51,2.91,3.26,1.9,2.37,2.62,2.92,1.99,2.53,
           2.69,3.06,2.25,2.8,2.9,3.26,1.99,2.22,2.34,2.65,
           2.07,2.35,2.45,2.65,2.21,3.11,3.21,3.55,1.89,2.56,
           2.74,3.1,1.96,2.4,2.76,3.1,2.13,2.67,3.11,3.4,
           2.17,2.65,3.07,3.39,1.76,2.08,2.1,3.01,2.21,2.71,
           3.15,3.45,1.61,1.86,2.21,2.54,2.12,2.65,3.03,3.34,
           1.76,2.1,2.3,2.63,2.03,2.48,2.88,3.26,1.97,2.53,
           2.78,3.07,2.29,2.77,3.2,3.52,1.95,2.38,2.58,2.88,
           2.08,2.59,3.03,3.37,1.87,2.33,2.59,2.91,1.5,1.53,
           1.48,1.59,2.16,2.67,3.11,3.46,2.15,2.45,2.69,3.05,
           2.2,2.63,3.06,3.4,2.08,2.53,2.99,3.38,2.03,2.65,
           3.04,3.32,1.92,2.47,2.66,2.94,1.97,2.56,3.01,3.31,
           2.09,2.72,3.19,3.48,1.96,2.65,2.97,3.26,2.01,2.62,
           2.97,3.25,2.23,2.87,3.11,3.4,2.08,2.77,3.06,3.35,
           2.1,2.87,3.12,3.46,2.17,2.69,3.02,3.3,1.81,2.42,
           2.94,3.36,1.93,2.48,2.77,3.04,2.19,2.76,3.09,3.42,
           1.86,2.67,2.98,3.26)

speed.data <- list ("n", "J", "K", "y", "laid", "rnid", "x")
speed.inits <- function (){
list (a=rnorm(J), b=rnorm(1), mu.a=rnorm(1), mu.b=rnorm(1),
    sigma.y=runif(1), sigma.a=runif(1), sigma.b=runif(1))}
speed.parameters <- c ("a", "b", "mu.a", "mu.b", "sigma.y", "sigma.a", "sigma.b")

speed.1 <- bugs (speed.data, speed.inits, speed.parameters,
             "speed.1.txt", n.chains=3, n.iter=10, debug=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could anyone help me with this please?